# How to select "child" HTML classes with getElementsByClassName

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am completely new to programming and started off by watching a few youtube videos so please go easy on me;

To test what I know and to try to learn something new I decided to make an Excel Macro that would pull information off of a local music venue's website about upcoming live shows.  I started by using the method: getElementsByClassName and specifically identifying how many classes of the same name appeared in the HTML above it IE:

```
    Dim Headliner As String
    Headliner = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("headliner summary")(2).innerText)
```

Unfortunately I found that on some pages more or less promos would bump the "headliner summary" class I am looking for up or down the screen.

Luckily "headliner summary" is a subclass of "event-info" which is very consistent across the site.  Obviously I can change my code to be:

```
    Dim Headliner As String
    Headliner = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("event-info")(0).innerText)
```

But now I have way more information than what I am looking for.  Is there a way to select a class and sub-class?

Where can I find a good reference document that describes methods? Are there any reference documents specifically about scraping data from the HTML websites?

Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to make suggestions without samples of the html source you're dealing with, or a URL to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<H5>` is not a class. The first code sample should be `Doc.getElementsByTagName("h5")(2).innerText` to get the display text from third `<H5>` element within the document.

If this still produces inconsistencies then perhaps looking through the `H5` elements for the first `<H5 class="event-info">` will return the correct result.

```
Dim Headliner As String
Dim e As mshtml.IHTMLElement, ec As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
Set ec = Doc.getElementsByTagName("h5")
For Each e In ec
    If e.className = "event-info" Then
        Headliner = Trim(e.innerText)
        Exit For
    End If
Next e
Set e = Nothing: Set ec = Nothing
```

There isn't enough sample data to be sure but this also may work consistently.

```
Headliner = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("event-info")(0).getElementsByTagName("h5")(0).innerText)
```

in the latter, I've assumed that you are looking for the first `<H5>` element within the first element (`<DIV>` perhaps...?). You really haven't given enough information on what type of element is using the *event-info* class so I don't know whether to look at it as an `<H5>` within another element like `<DIV class="event-info">` or an actual `<H5 class="event-info">`.

Comment: Great thank you - it looks like I mixed up the two things I tried, h5 was something I punched in from before when I was attempting to do this by ID (i think ??)  Your last line of code there works perfect for what I was trying to do.